# Error Flutter - The method 'configure' isn't defined for the type 'FirebaseMessaging'

Tags: flutter, dart

when updating my App, the following error is appearing, can someone help me with my code?

**Error: The method 'configure' isn't defined for the type 'FirebaseMessaging'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'configure'.**

Code:

```
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';

class PushNotification {
  final FirebaseMessaging _fcm = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  
  Future initialize() async {
    _fcm.configure(
//      this callback is used when the app runs on the foreground
        onMessage: handleOnMessage,
//        used when the app is closed completely and is launched using the notification
        onLaunch: handleOnLaunch,
//        when its on the background and opened using the notification drawer
        onResume: handleOnResume);
  }

  Future handleOnMessage(Map<String, dynamic> data) async {
    print("=== data = ${data.toString()}");
  }

  Future handleOnLaunch(Map<String, dynamic> data) async {
    print("=== data = ${data.toString()}");
  }

  Future handleOnResume(Map<String, dynamic> data) async {
    print("=== data = ${data.toString()}");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the newest version of firebase_messaging, the `configure` method does not exists.
You can see all possible methods in the official [API reference](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_messaging/latest/firebase_messaging/FirebaseMessaging-class.html).

I recommend checking the official [Getting Started](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/overview/) to have a compatible code with the latest version.